# Обслуживающий пул приложений, запросил повторный запуск,

Tags: windows, asp.net, сервер, iis, windows-server-2012

C недавнего времени в системном журнале заметил сообщение:

**Рабочий процесс с идентификатором процесса "8128", обслуживающий пул приложений "name", запросил повторный запуск, так как в рабочем процессе достигнут предел допустимого времени обработки.**

Для нормальной работоспособности приложения это проблема. Логи самого приложения каких либо ошибок не фиксируют, уже только сам момент останова и запуска проекта.

Используется: OS Windows Server 2012 r2, IIS 8, MSSQL 2012, ASP.NET WebForms

Может кто сталкивался с подобным?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

[image: screen_iis]

Как видно на скрине - это всё настраивается в IIS Manager. По умолчанию перезапуск пула происходит каждые 1740 минут.